# How can I return JSON from a Rust (Rocket) HTTP endpoint?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

What is the easiest way to return Json via Rocket in Rust?

```
#[post("/route", data = "<data>")]
fn route(someVariable: String) -> String {
    // How can I return a json response here? {"a": "{someVariable}")
}
```

I tried: `content::Json()` but it seemed too static for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're finding `content::Json()` too static you can use the `rocket_contrib` package. Using this package will allow you to pass in a struct that implements `Deserialize` from the serde package

```rust
use rocket_contrib::json::Json;
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct User {
  name: String,
  age: u8,
  alive: bool, 
}

#[post("/route", data = "<data>")]
fn route(someVariable: String) -> String {
    let user = User {
        name: "Jon Snow".to_string(),
        age: 21,
        alive: true,
    };
    Json(user_from_id)
}
```

Make sure you add the dependencies to your `Cargo.toml`

```ini
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
rocket_contrib = "0.4"
```

More information on rocket_contrib https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket_contrib/json/struct.Json.html

Comment: How do I not create a struct to deserialize but still respond a Json dynamically. Basically what if I don't know what my Response JSON schema is. Without using a struct, if I pass a String representation of a JSON, then it's giving that String in the response and not a JSON

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be just using serde_json:

```
serde_json::to_string(&MyStructObject);
```

serde_json::to_string will return a Result< String >  where the string is a json string. Finally in your Cargo.toml you need to have the following:

```
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 0.5, you don't need `rocket_contrib`, just the `json` feature on the Rocket crate:

```rust
use rocket::serde::{Serialize, json::Json};

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(crate = "rocket::serde")]
struct Task { /* .. */ }

#[get("/todo")]
fn todo() -> Json<Task> {
    Json(Task { /* .. */ })
}
```

[Example from here](https://rocket.rs/v0.5/guide/responses/#json)